# Why are there multiple MessageSID permutations in the Twilio Message response?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is a more general question for trying to understand why there are what appear to be 3 different permutations of essentially the same key-value in the vanilla Twilio api response back either when a `message` resource is returned or webhook'd to a third party application.

Here is the abridged JSON response returned to a requesting client:

```
//mock message id values
{ "SmsMessageSid": "MM2fb7744c9a752cb554b4a6371c6756d8",
  //... abridged
    "SmsSid": "MM2fb7744c9a752cb554b4a6371c6756d8",
//...abridged
    "MessageSid": "MM2fb7744c9a752cb554b4a6371c6756d8"
}
```

Google surfaces a [support doc](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134387-What-is-a-Message-SID-) on MessageSid, but nothing else is clear on the data dictionary for the other two properties.

My questions are:

1. Why are there 3 keys with the same value?
2. Are there any instances in which those values would be different for any of the keys?
3. Which key-value should I persist if I want to save the id for this specific message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

[SMS Request Parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters)

MessageSid  A 34 character unique identifier for the message. May be used to later retrieve this message from the REST API.

SmsSid  Same value as MessageSid. Deprecated and included for backward compatibility.

Use MessageSid

Comment: Nice, thanks for the insight. Do you have any thoughts on the `SmsMessageSid` property? Same deal as `SmsSid`?

Comment: I would have to say legacy as well. The reason I say that is the /Messages resource, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource,  is used for more then just SMS today, it is also used for WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger which are not SMS (and thus the move to MessageSid and away from SmsSid).

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Alan's answer is correct. We ended up writing a blog post based on this question! You can check it out here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/programmable-messaging-sids

Comment: thanks @ecmoy , looks like a fairly new blog post. I'm glad my question could contribute to some of the content marketing & developer advocacy efforts ;) Appreciate the thought put into it!